# The spherically symmetric metric and the general metric

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry

In Ta-Pei Cheng's Relativity, Gravitation and Cosmology [book](http://202.38.64.11/%7Ejmy/documents/ebooks/Cheng,%20Oxford%202005Relativity,%20Gravitation,%20and%20Cosmology.pdf), pg. 88, it was stated that the infinitesimal invariant interval $ds^2=g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ for a spherically symmetric metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is:
$$ds^2=Ad\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r}+B(\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r})^2+Cdt(\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r})+Ddt^2$$
where $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ are scalar functions of $t$ and $\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}$.

Is it correct to say that for a general metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ (not necessarily spherically symmetric), the invariant interval $ds^2$ will be the similar as above, i.e.

$$ds^2=Ad\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r}+B(\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r})^2+Cdt(\vec{r}\cdot d\vec{r})+Ddt^2$$
but now with $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ being scalar functions of $t$ and $\vec{r}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spherical symmetry implies that the metric is independent of angles, that is, where you are standing on a spherical surface. Basically, entire surface of the sphere (at every r) looks the same everywhere on it. Mathematically, this translates to the metric coefficients, $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ being independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinates.

If you forgo spherical symmetry, in the most general metric, the coefficients $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ will be functions of $r$, $\theta$, and $\phi$.

About the dependence on $t$, if a metric is time-independent people generally add a qualifier of steady and/or stationary. So when you are talking about just a spherically symmetric metric, the metric coefficients depend on $t$ anyway in general.

Answer (score 4):

To describe the most general spacetime metric you need 10 functions (the metric is a symmetric 4x4 matrix). However, using the transformation law for the metric, you can always choose a new coordinate system in which you eliminate 4 of the above 10 functions. Thus, the most general metric (regardless of whether you represent it in spherical coordinates) has 6 free functions. In your example you have only 4 functions: $A, B, C$ and $D$, so it cannot describe the most general spacetime.

By the way, note that the very meaning of the coordinate system is not given a priory. So, before you get to know more about the details of your spacetime, it is meaningless to say, for example, that $\vec{r}$ is the usual radial vector.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. There are more possible terms one can add that are forbidden by spherical symmetry. For example, rotations in some direction $\theta$ are characterised by a term $~dtd\theta$ in the metric. Expanding your metric using $d \vec{r} \cdot d \vec{r}=d r^{2}+r^{2}\left(d \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta d \phi^{2}\right)$, we see that

$$
d s^{2}=A\left[d r^{2}+r^{2}\left(d \theta^{2}+\sin ^{2} \theta d \phi^{2}\right)\right]+B r^{2} d r^{2}+C r d r d t+D d t^{2}
$$

Since there are no terms that go like $dtd\theta$ or $dtd\phi$, we know that this can't be the most general metric.

Comment: Why the downvote?